# How does Gradle resolve plugins not listed in the Gradle Plugin Portal?

Tags: gradle, spring-security, gradle-plugin

In the `spring-security` project, in the [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/build.gradle) file, the following plugins are made available:

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.nohttp'
apply plugin: 'locks'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.convention.root'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.security.update-dependencies'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.security.sagan'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.github.milestone'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.github.changelog'
```

About the first plugin in the list (`io.spring.nohttp`) - in the [Gradle - Plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/) page, if in the `Search Gradle plugins` text field is used the `io.spring.nohttp` term, appears the [io.spring.nohttp](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.nohttp) result - and can be opened the Owner: [Spring IO](https://plugins.gradle.org/u/spring), where appears many plugins of the same owner. If you open in a new tab page for some of them, you are going to observe it works with two different accounts in GitHub - for example:

- [io.spring.nohttp](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.nohttp) -> `https://github.com/spring-io/nohttp` (the `spring-io` user)
- [io.spring.dependency-management](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management) -> `https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin` (the `spring-gradle-plugins` user)

So, I can analyze and understand how each plugin works or what it does.

For other plugin - `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` - it happens the same experience shared above

**Reason of this post**: for many of the others plugins, if I try to search other plugin, for example about `Sagan` - if in the textfield is used the `org.springframework.security.sagan` term, it does not return a result (even if only the `sagan` term is used) - but I know that exists in GitHub the [spring-io/sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan) project, is it the plugin right?

So how is resolved the plugins that "theoretically" does not exist in the *Gradle Plugins* page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the plugins defined by `spring-security` are not published to the Gradle Plugin Portal, nor are they in any other repository. However, it works because projects can define custom plugins using the [`buildSrc`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/main/buildSrc) directory also.

For example, the plugin with ID `org.springframework.security.sagan` is defined in the respective [`buildSrc/build.gradle`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/buildSrc/build.gradle#L47):

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        sagan {
            id = "org.springframework.security.sagan"
            implementationClass = "org.springframework.gradle.sagan.SaganPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

`spring-io/sagan` itself is not a Gradle plugin.

Read more about the mechanics in the official Gradle docs:

- [Use buildSrc to abstract imperative logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)
- [Packaging a plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:packaging_a_plugin)

Comment: `spring-io/sagan itself is not a Gradle plugin` even if that is correct - is confuse at a first glance because is declared within the `gradlePlugin` and `plugins` blocks

Comment: @ManuelJordan I agree, it's not immediately obvious where a plugin may come from.

Answer (score 0):

In gradle, plugins are specified by an id with some exception for embedded plugins.  The first time you specify a plugin you also specify the version of that plugin.  Gradle has some rules about the version number being literal and not a variable in certain contexts due to the concept of being idempotent.  Once Gradle knows about which version of a plugin you are using, you don't need to specify the version number again, so you'll see many buildscripts where the version number is not specified. Sometimes the jar that contains the implementation for a particular plugin will actually contain the implementation for several plugins.  If that's the case, all those plugins have their own id.  The reason for mentioning this, is if you defined any of the plugins contained in the jar, you'll probably find out that you don't need to specify the version of another plugin in that same jar.  When Gradle loads a jar containing a plugin, it also reads the META-INFO/gradle-plugins directory and learns about all the plugin id's that the implementation jar contains. In other words, if you're using one of the plugins in the implementation jar, Gradle assumes that you're probably going to use other plugins contained in that same implementation jar so you can skip mentioning the version. Those are just some of the details that just confuses new Gradle users because you see coding examples where the version is specified and examples where the version is not specified.

With all that said, how does Gradle find a plugin using the plugin id?  Gradle looks in each defined repository in the order that the repositories are define.  It gets the implementation from the first repository that contains the plugin with the given id.  How does Gradle find the implementation jar associated with a given id. Let's assume you're looking for "io.spring.convention.root".  Gradle looks for the artifact (group="io.spring.convention.root", artifact="io.spring.convention.root.gradle.plugin", version=?)  If it can't find that artifact, that repository does not contain that plugin.  If it finds that artifact, it then retreives the "maven-metadata.xml" file associated with that plugin. That metadata will contain a dependency on the artifact that contains the jar file that implements the plugin.  Gradle then downloads that implementation.